# Pushing to an array inside of a loop inside of a callback function

Tags: node.js

I have a loop that I need to run inside of a callback, unfortunately accessing the array outside of the callback leaves me with a blank array. I know why this happens, but I want to know the best solution to tackle this.

```
Gallery.prototype.getGallery = function(cb) {
self = this;
var cos = new pb.CustomObjectService();
var ms = new pb.MediaService();

var s = [];

cos.loadTypeByName('Gallery Image', function(err, gallery){

    cos.findByType(gallery._id.toString(), function(err, rpy){

        for(var i = 0; i < rpy.length; i++){
            ms.loadById(rpy[i].Image, function(e,r){
                s.push(r.location);
                console.log(r.location); /* <-- logs expected data */
            });     
       }
       console.log(s[0]); /* <-- this is undefined  */
    });
});
};
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this question has been asked and answered dozens of times on SO. Why would you imagine that the array would be populated before the async call has commpleted? The callback is being executed asynchronously--that means "sometime in the future". Unless you have a time machine, you cannot access variables that are not going be set until some time in the future.

Comment: Thanks torazaburo, as I stated, I know why... the QUESTION IS what is the most elegant way to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with a call to `async.*`; in this case `async.map` seems right. Pass a callback to `async.map`; it will be invoked when all the individual calls to `ms.loadById` are done, with the array of results.

```
async.map(
    rpy, 
    function(elt, callback) {
        ms.loadById(elt.Image, callback);
    },
    function(err, data) {
        // comes here after all individual async calls have completed
        // check errors; array of results is in data
    }
);
```

If you want to go into the promises world, then wrap the calls to `ms.loadById` in a promise. Here's a roll-your-own version, but various versions of what is usually called `promisify` are also out there.

```
function loadByIdPromise(elt) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ms.loadById(elt.image, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Then do a `Promise.all` on the resulting promises:

```
Promise.all(rpy.map(loadByIdPromise))
    .then(function(data) {
        // comes here when all individual async calls complete successfully
        // data is your array of results
    });
```

Using the promises style, your entire code would look like:

```
loadTypeByNamePromise('Gallery Image') .
    then(function(gallery) { return findByTypePromise(gallery._id.toString(); }) . 
    then(function(rpy)     { return Promise.all(rpy.map(loadByIdPromise)); }) .
    then(function(results) { /* do something with [results] */ });
```